# Update query with months as columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Need help to write a query to update budget data with actual data in a table with 12 months as columns.

I cannot change the table schema.

Table: `Budget2021`

```
Create table Budget2021
(
Account int identity,
Jan_Actual int,
Jan_Budget int,
Feb_Actual int,
Feb_Budget int,
Mar_Actual int,
Mar_Budget int,
Apr_Actual int,
Apr_Budget int,
May_Actual int,
May_Budget int,
Jun_Actual int,
Jun_Budget int,
Jul_Actual int,
Jul_Budget int,
Aug_Actual int,
Aug_Budget int,
Sep_Actual int,
Sep_Budget int,
oct_Actual int,
oct_Budget int,
Nov_Actual int,
Nov_Budget int,
Dec_Actual int,
Dec_Budget int,
)

Insert into Budget2021 values (100,200,
300,100,
4000,1000,
50,50,
1000,1000,
2000,2000,
3000,3000,
4000,4000,
5000,5000,
50,50,
1000,1000,
2000,2000)
```

I have to update the `Budget` column to match the `Actual` column for all the previous months. Needs to be done in a job every month.

For example in April, I have to update the Jan, Feb, Mar `Budget` columns with `Actual` column.

In June, should copy for the months Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr and May

Can someone please help me with a query to do this? (T-SQL)

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide sample data and desired output?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I got you right you could use a parameter month (2 - 13, 2 = Feb, 13 = Jan next Year) :

```
Update Budget2021
      set Jan_Budget = CASE WHEN @month > 1 THEN Jan_Actual 
      ELSE Jan_Budget,
      Feb_Budget = CASE WHEN @month > 2 THEN Feb_Actual 
      ELSE feb_Budget,
      ...
      Dec_Budget = CASE WHEN @month > 12 THEN Dec_Actual 
      ELSE Dec_Budget
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @Sql as varchar(max)
select @Sql =(
        select  distinct 
                ' ' + left(name, 3) + '_Budget = ' + left(name, 3) + '_Actual,'  AS [text()]
        from sys.all_columns
        where object_id = OBJECT_ID('Budget2021')
        and column_id < (
                            select min(column_id)
                            from sys.all_columns
                            where object_id = OBJECT_ID('Budget2021')
                            and left(name , 3) =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()), 100)
                        )
        and name <> 'Account'
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    )

Set @Sql = 'update Budget2021 set ' + left( @Sql , len(@Sql) - 1)

execute(@Sql)
```